# How to loop over dictionary to display in frontend in django and implement user input

Tags: python, django, api, tweepy

Ive created my own dictionary from the tweepy api results.

it displays the data I want on the frontend. However, how do I go about looping over my dictionary so html is produced for each dictionary created.

I also wish to have user input determine the query parameter but not sure how do it

This is what I've tried but no avail..

```
{% for tweet in twitter_data %}
        <div class="tweet-container">

            <img src="{{twitter_data.profile_dp}}" alt="avatar" class="avatar" />

            <time class="tweet-time">{{twitter_data.created_at}}</time>

            <div class="push">

                <div class="user">
                    <div class="user-string"><span class="name">{{twitter_data.user_name}}</span><span
                            class="username">@{{twitter_data.user_screen_name}}</span></div>
                </div>

                <blockquote class="tweet"><span class="at">@lorem_bot </span>{{twitter_data.text}} <span
                        class="tag">#lorem2015</span></blockquote>

                <div class="icons">
                    <i class="fa fa-reply"><span class="icon-number"> 10</span></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-retweet"><span class="icon-number"> {{twitter_data.retweet_count}}</span></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star"><span class="icon-number"> {{twitter_data.fav_count}}</span></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        {% end for %}
```

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
import tweepy
import json

# Create your views here.
CONSUMER_KEY = 'm'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'Xu'
ACCESS_KEY = '116'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'wz'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)


def index(requests):

    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                               query="xbox",
                               q="{xbox}",
                               count=1,
                               result_type="recent",
                               include_entities=True,
                               lang="en").items():

        twitter_data = {
            'text': tweet.text,
            'user_name': tweet.user.name,
            'user_screen_name': tweet.user.screen_name,
            'created_at': tweet.created_at,
            'profile_dp': tweet.user.profile_image_url,
            'retweet_count': tweet.retweet_count,
            'fav_count': tweet.favorite_count

        }

    context = {'twitter_data': twitter_data}
    return render(requests, 'twitter/twitter.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run multiple loops in your template. You only need to save those tweet objects as a list in your view and then loop over them in the template.

```
#views.py    
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                                   query="xbox",
                                   q="{xbox}",
                                   count=1,
                                   result_type="recent",
                                   include_entities=True,
                                   lang="en").items()

context = {'tweets': tweets}
```

Then in your template:

```
{% for tweet in tweets %}
   {{ tweet.text }}
   {{ tweet.user.name }}
   {{ tweet.retweet_count }}
{% endfor %}
```

etc....